# IF array validacion javascript

Tags: javascript, array, condiciones

hola tengo el siguiente arreglo en javascript
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quisiera hacer una validacion con if donde verifique si el valor proporcionado por el usuario(procedures) se encuentra en este array (quirurjico)habilite unos campos en un formulario se como habilitar/deshabilitar los campos pero no se como verificar esta lista del array con lo que escriba el usuario hasta el momento tengo algo como esto.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function habilitar() {
    const case1 = '735301 - ASISTENCIA DEL PARTO CON O SIN EPISIORRAFIA O PERINEORRAFIA';
    const case2 = '735930 - ASISTENCIA DEL PARTO ESPONTÁNEO GEMELAR O MÚLTIPLE';
    const case3 = '735931 - ASISTENCIA DEL PARTO INTERVENIDO GEMELAR O MÚLTIPLE';
    const case4 = '735980 - OTRA ASISTENCIA MANUAL DEL PARTO ESPONTÁNEO';
    const procedures = document.getElementById('inputprocedures');
    const attention = document.getElementById('personal_attention');
    const mainDiagnosis = document.getElementById('main_diagnosis');
    const fDiagnosisRel = document.getElementById('f_related_code');
    const sDiagnosisRel = document.getElementById('s_related_code');
    const relWay = document.getElementById('realization_way_surgical_act');
    
     if (case1 == procedures.value) {
     attention.disabled = false; 
     }else if(case2 == procedures.value){
     attention.disabled = false;
     }else if (case3 == procedures.value){
     attention.disabled = false;
     }else if (case4 == procedures.value){
     attention.disabled = false;
     }else{ 
     attention.disabled = true;
     }
```

////////////////////////////esta parte es la que deseo validar con la lista del array ://///////////////////////////

```
 var quirurjico = <?php echo json_encode($Quirurjicos) ?>;
    var list =quirurjico.length;
    for(var i = 0;i<list;i++){
    console.log(quirurjico[i]);
    }

        if (quirurjico[i] === procedures.value) {
             
          mainDiagnosis.disabled = false;
          fDiagnosisRel.disabled = false;
          sDiagnosisRel.disabled = false;
          relWay.disabled = false;
     } else {
        mainDiagnosis.disabled = true;
        fDiagnosisRel.disabled = true;
        sDiagnosisRel.disabled = true;
        relWay.disabled = true; 
     }
     
     } 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No se muy bien lo que quieres comparar. no se que campo quieres validar contra que campo del array y tampoco estoy seguro como se llama el array.

Por lo poco que he entendido podrías hacer algo así.

```
const exists = quirurjico.some(x => x.name === procedures.value);
```

array.some te devuelve true si algún elemento del array cumple la condición y false si ninguno la cumple

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que comentas, te podría ir bien la función includes().
Sería algo así:

```
if(quirurjico.includes(procedure.value));
```

Esta función determina si el array contiene el elemento pasado como argumento, si lo contiene devuelve true, en caso contrario devuelve false.

Comment: hola el array viene de una query sql entonces selecciona los name:procedimientos entonces no se si a la hora de recorrer el array este vien ya que tiene la propiedad name: pero lo que necesito es comparar cada procedimiento con el procedure.value que es lo que escribe el usuario ya lo intente con includes y no permitio

Comment: Qué error te da?

Comment: hola no da error simplemente no hace la validacion supongo que mi array esta mal planteado xq es una consulta sql mira aca hay mas detalles https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/538420/problema-al-hacer-una-validacion-sobre-un-aray-asociativo