# problema al hacer una validacion sobre un array asociativo

Tags: javascript, php, array, arraylist

hola hice una consulta mysql en php y los resultados  o array los asigne a una variable[] pase el array variable[] a javascript con json-encode si imprimo el array Variable[] en javascrip  por consola sale de la siguiente manera:

```
object{ name: "procedimiento medico1"},
object{ name: "procedimiento medico2"},
object{ name: "procedimiento medico3"},
object{ name: "procedimiento medico4"}, etc son como 4mil filas.
```

El problema esta que al querer usar un ciclo for o for_each para hacer una validacion con if/else donde si el usuario ingresa un procedimiento medico y este se encuentra en mi array VAriable[] haga una cosa u otra;tengo problemas ya que dentro del array todas las filas u objetos tienen la propiedad o key **name:** entonces no validad dentro de todo el arreglo si existe dicho procedimiento como puedo solucionar esto? puedo quitarle la propiedad name al array variable[] y que solo quede la lista asi:

```
ej array [
"procedimiento medico1",
"procedimiento medico2",
"procedimiento medico3",
 etc]
```

la consula sql donde proviene el array es esta:

```
$Quirurjicos=DB::table('cups')->select('name')->where('description','=','Sección 00 PROCEDIMIENTOS QUIRÚRGICOS E INTERVENCIONISTAS')->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías usar la función `find()` para encontrar el procedimiento ingresado por el usuario. Esta función iterará cada objeto de array, devolviéndote el que coincida con tu patrón de búsqueda (en caso de encontrarlo, si no lo encuentra te devolvería `undefined`), que en tu caso es cuando el atributo "name" del objeto sea igual al procedimiento ingresado por el usuario.

```js
const procedimientos = [
  { name: 'procedimiento médico 1' },
  { name: 'procedimiento médico 2' },
  { name: 'procedimiento médico 3' },
  { name: 'procedimiento médico 4' },
]
const buscadoPorUsuario = 'procedimiento médico 3'

if (procedimientos.find((procedimiento) => procedimiento.name === buscadoPorUsuario)) {
  console.log('El procedimiento se ha encontrado')
}
else {
  console.log('El procedimiento NO se ha encontrado')
}
```

**Referencia:** [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)